# How to make a boost::shared_ptr<T> for global var

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was wondering how to create a `boost::shared_ptr<T>` global variable for a `tf::TransformListener` object? I am encountering the same problem as in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12962/a-strange-problem-about-rosinit/) posted a while ago but I don't know enough about `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

Can someone explain how I can declare and initialize `boost::shared_ptr<T>` with respect to `tf::TransformListener`? Many thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57919/how-to-make-a-boost::shared_ptr%3Ct%3E-for-global-var/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Martin,

```
boost::shared_ptr<tf::TransformListener> tf_ptr;

...

int main(int argc, const char* argv []) {

  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
  tf_ptr.reset(new tf::TransformListener);

  ... do more stuff here. Use tf_ptr as a regular pointer for the most part ...

  return 0;
}
```

The comments in [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/32684/how-to-use-tf-listener/) also explain the same answer.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-12**:
Thanks for the quick reply piyushk! I tried this but now I am back to getting the error: reference to ‘transform’ is ambiguous. candidates are: tf::StampedTransform transform. Do I need to make StampedTransform a shared_ptr too? the variable transform is what I need in my callback

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-12**:
Can you give the code sample producing that.

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-03-12**:
Hey dornhege, I put the code into another answer (forgetting that I could edit my own question haha)